# Pandas setting a value on a copy of a slice error when updating columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a 3 column pandas dataframe namely: **col1, col2, col3**
I want to update the dataframe for col1 to be equal col where col 3 = 0
The below code makes the update successfully but its throwing a warning about *setting a value on a copy of a slice*

```
df.col1.loc[df.col3==0] = df.col2.loc[df.col3==0]
```

Any way to fix the code to remove the warning?

Comment: try this: 
import warnings; warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

Comment: I have done this in the past, but I am afraid switching off the warning may cause an error to slide past unnoticed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) instead [`Series.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.loc.html):

```
#cache to variable
mask = df.col3 == 0
df.loc[mask, 'col1'] = df.loc[mask, 'col2']
```

There are also another possible ways - [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) or [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].mask(mask, df['col2'])

df['col1'] = np.where(mask, df['col2'], df['col1'])
```

Comment: Thank you. This sorted out my issue and I finally have understood the reasoning behind the warning.